# Given a directrix and a focus, can we use an arbitrary curve as the directrix?

Tags: conic-sections, locus

A parabola is defined as the set of points equidistant from a directrix *line* and a focus point. But what if we allow the directrix to be an arbitrary curve, including possibly another parabola? What happens?

My attempts so far...

Let $(f, \phi)$ represent the focus point F.
Let $(q, Q)$ represent points on the directrix curve K.
Let $(x,y)$ represent a point P on the curve that satisfies the condition : $$distance (FP) = distance (KP)$$

By applying the condition, we get the following relation between F, K and P:

$$y = \frac{(x-f)^2 - (x-q)^2}{2(\phi-Q)} + \frac{\phi+Q}{2} \hspace{10mm}E1 $$

This comes from applying the distance formula to the above condition, then expanding and simplifying. Let’s test this expression on the directrix curve $K=(x,-1)$ and the focus $F=(0,1)$. Plugging this into the above expression, we get
$$y = \frac{(x-0)^2 - (x-x)^2}{2(1-(-1)} + \frac{1+(-1)}{2} = \frac{x^2}{4} $$
Which works. But for some reason, I can’t make sense of E1. Is it general enough? How can I use it for parabolas tilted at some angle e.g. if the directrix is the line defined by $K(q,Q) = (q,2q)$ and the focus is at $F(f,\phi) = (0,1)$ then intuitively the parabola should be slanted. But how can I describe such a parabola with E1, if E1 is correct?

Further motivation - what if the directrix curve is $K(q,Q) = (q,cos(q))$ and the focus is at $(0,1)$? What curve described by $(x,y)$ satisfies E1?

Comment: Distance $KP$ must be orthogonal to $K$. In addition, from a generic point $P$ several different normal lines could be issued to a generic curve.

Comment: I don't understand your equation $\#1$.    Finding the distance from a point to a general curve is non-trivial.

Comment: @lulu - The weird symbols are to avoid excessive use of subscripts. F(f, \phi) is the focus. It's a single point. K(q,Q) represents an arbitrary point on the directrix. In the case of a line, K might be (q=x, Q=-2). I used q instead of x because for some parabolas (e.g the slanted ones), the point P(x,y) on the parabola doesn't necessarily have the same x-value as the directrix line. Darn, I wish I could draw what I'm trying to describe.  The equation E1 is derived by applying the distance formula to FP and KP.

Comment: I don't understand.  Of course, if you are handed the closest point on the curve, you can get a simple expression for the distance...but finding that point (which may not be unique)  is non-trivial.

Comment: To stress:  this issue is avoided when you use a straight line parallel to the $x-$axis.  In that case, the nearest point is the one  that has the same $x-$coordinate.

Comment: I think @Intelligenti pauca has cleared things up. So, start with a directrix curve described by K(q,Q) as well as a focus F(f,$\phi$) somewhere in the plane. From K, *extend a normal N*. Draw a line from F to N until it intersects N at P(x,y). If distance (FP) equals distance (KP) , then P satisfies the parabola-inspired equidistance condition. If K(q,Q) is a straight line then drawing normals is easy and P is guaranteed to be a parabola. If K(q,Q) is some curve like cos(x), then drawing normals is not that easy and who knows what P(x,y) even traces out. Is this what you meant @lulu?

Comment: @lulu I understand you now. I'm not that great at math, but I'm curious to know what P(x,y) traces out if we let focus be (0,1) and directrix be (x,cosx). A rough sketch suggests some weird stretched out sinusoidal curve, but  that's proof by picture so it doesn't count.

Comment: To stress: drawing normals is not quite the same as minimizing distance.  A priori a given point might lie on several normals. Of course the shortest path is going to be a normal, under standard assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer: just to show the locus proposed by the OP in a comment (easily made with GeoGebra):

[image]

The same locus when the "directrix" is parabola $y=x^2$, and the focus the focus of the parabola.

[image]